# Proof check: $\sum_{k=1}^n\arctan\frac{1}{2k^2}=\arctan\frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, solution-verification, contest-math

It is clearly true for $n = 1$, so assume it is true for $n = k$, for some integer $k \ge 1$. That is,
$$\sum_{l = 1}^k \arctan \frac{1}{2l^2} = \arctan \frac{k}{k + 1}$$ is true for some $k \ge 1$.
If that is the case, then
$$\sum_{l = 1}^{k+1} \arctan \frac{1}{2l^2} = \arctan \frac{k}{k + 1} + \arctan \frac{1}{2(k+1)^2}$$
is true as well. Then note that
$$((k + 1) + ki) (2(k+1)^2 + i) = z,$$
for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Expanding, we get that
\begin{align*}
2k^3 + 6k^2 + 5k + 2 &= \mathbf{Re}(z), \\
2k^3 + 4k^2 + 3k + 1 &= \mathbf{Im}(z). 
\end{align*}
We wish to show that
$$\arctan \frac{k}{k + 1} + \arctan \frac{1}{2(k+1)^2} = \arctan \frac{k + 1}{k + 2}.$$
If that were true, then their real and imaginary parts were equal; that is, there
would exist a solution to $\mathbf{Re}(z) = k + 2$ and $\mathbf{Im}(z) = k + 1$.
We find that from $\mathbf{Re}(z) = k + 2$ it follows that $(k + 1)(k + 2) = 0$ and from
$\mathbf{Im}(z) = k + 1$, it follows that that $(k + 1)^2 = 0$. Indeed, it is clear that
the system has the unique solution $k = -1$ for which the two imaginary numbers are equal.
Since such a value of $k$ exists, the argument of both complex numbers must also be equal,
and we're done.

Comment: Why not to use $$\tan ^{-1}(a)+\tan ^{-1}(b)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a+b}{1-a b}\right)$$ for an immediate result

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I do not have that result memorized, and saw this approach first.

Comment: You must know it. It is a very imprtant identity. To prove it, apply $\tan(.)$ on both sides  https://www.math-only-math.com/arctan-x-plus-arctan-y.html

Comment: You can derive it with complex numbers of course, $\arctan(a)=\arg(1+ai)$.